# Math Game using PHP

Tags: php, math, jquery, comet

I want to develop game that generates random simple math equations.

- easy - `4+5`, `5-6` (operator used are +,-)
- medium - `4*5`, `5/6` (operator used are +,-,*,/)
- difficult - `4*5/7`, `5/6-5` (operator used are +,-,*,/)

Now I think this can be done simply generating every character randome, i.e. generate two random numbers and then generate a random operator and using them together and keeping conditions to find answer which will also check answer entered by user.

But that would be too rookie to code I guess. I want to know if this is the right way or if I should use any pre-defined math library available for PHP. As of now I have to just work with 4 operators but in future it is possible that I need to implement more complex equations.

Also, I have to implement multiplayer mode and I am thinking to use Comet so that users can play at same time together. 
Should I be using PHP and MySQL to create this game or shall I create this using AJAX/JQuery?

Comment: If you're using AJAX/jQuery, you're gonna have to use PHP and MySQL, so go ahead and use them all if you don't want the user having to refresh the page every so often.

Comment: Using PHP and mysql , You can achieve your targets and can be extended to multiplayed mode as well. For math function , Chk this out http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.math.php

Comment: Thanks titanium and gout. I wonder how to implement multiplayer mode ? like the screen with same equation can be seen by all players playing the game. ie all players have to finish game to get the summary list with their scores.... Shall I use comet technology or ajax ?

Comment: You may want to start by having a look at things like [reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) or [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) (and links therein).

Comment: Thnks Nico..so u mean that I should generate equation string using my logic and then should use your suggested method you recommended to solve the equation  ???

Comment: I would directly generate reverse Polish notation, which is easy to generate solve. You can then output the equation in "classic" notation (plenty of algorithms exist to go between the two notations). Your method is somehow limited in having number-operator-number-operator and so on and, unless you are limiting yourself to numbers between 0 and 9, that will never generate something like `10+15`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a array of operators, and generate the operands random;

```
$operarors = array( '+', '-', '*' );
$operator = $operarors[rand(0,2)];
$leftop = rand(0,10);
$rightop = $rand(0,10);

echo "the math: $leftop $operator $rightop = ??";
```

Comment: Thanks jvdberg...tat is indeed simple to implement...:)